# what is Gang of Four design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, gang-of-four

I have recently come to know that there is a design pattern in Java called Gang of Four (GoF). I'm not able to understand what it is and what's its use. Can anybody make me clear on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GangOfFour

Comment: I believe GoF is not a design pattern, but a designation of the authors of a book: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns

Comment: This is not the place to get other people to do your research for you.  Google and Wikipedia are your friend.  That said, http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx is a good repository for information on design patterns.

Comment: http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/

Comment: http://w3sDesign.com GoF Design Patterns

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> The authors of the [DesignPatternsBook](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DesignPatternsBook) came to be known as the **"Gang of Four."** The name of the book ("Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software") is too long for e-mail, so "book by the gang of four" became a shorthand name for it.
>
> After all, it isn't the ONLY book on patterns. That got shortened to "GOF book", which is pretty cryptic the first time you hear it.

Source: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GangOfFour

Answer (score 16):

Gang of Four is not a design pattern, it is the colloquial name for the book *"Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software"* by Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson and John Vlissides (hence Gang of Four). Note that Gang of Four or GoF is used to refer to either the group of authors or the book itself.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns

Answer (score 3):

Gang Of Four (GOF) refers to the authors of the book:

> Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software

From [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns):

> Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software is a
>   software engineering book describing recurring solutions to common
>   problems in software design. The book's authors are Erich Gamma,
>   Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson and John Vlissides with a foreword by
>   Grady Booch. The authors are often referred to as the Gang of Four,
>   GoF,or Go4

Comment: The "Gang of Four":
Erich Gamma,
Richard Helm,
Ralph Johnson,
John Vlissides